# Put/Take commands for GUI C#

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have a console application I am now creating a GUI for it.

My GUI is simply a text block that prints text to screen, a Textbox where a user can enter text and a button for the user to submit their text.

I have done a very terrible job at this using the MainWindow.xaml.cs file that was created for me when I opened up VS. I have a DLL of my classes in my console app and all my GUI related code is in my button code on the GUI.

I mean it works but I figure it is very unorthodox. What I have now realized is that part of thew task involves me to upload all Put/Take related code, this is where I am confused, what is this?? I cannot find anything online about it. Now apologize in advance if I need to be more specific or add more information, due to my lack of knowledge I am very unsure what I need to my question, however, I mainly want an explanation of the purpose of the Put/Take commands?

Let me know if I should add more info to help you answer and what would be most useful.

Comment: There is no information in this question that gives anybody any idea what you are doing. You have posted no code and asked no question.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression from the wording of the task that Put/Take were a universal programming thing... they are not and it was specific to my task and another class they wanted me to implement